# Unable to access test resources

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins, junit

I have a file testPristineCopy.xlsx in ..\src\test\resources folder. In my unit test< i try and access it like this:

```
InputStream testInputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testPristineCopy.xlsx");
```

I get an error for this line when I tried running the unit test using JUnit. The stack trace is below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FileMagic.prepareToCheckMagic(FileMagic.java:148)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:175)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:149)
at com.cerner.form_upload.test.ExcelViewSheetTest.extractValuesTest(ExcelViewSheetTest.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Any idea what the problem is? I need these resources to be accessible for the test cases when they are run on Jenkins.

Comment: Have you added `src/test/resources` as source folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relative path to access any resource file under **src/test/resources** folder. Something like this.

```
InputStream testInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("src/test/resources/testPristineCopy.xlsx"));
```